# Java regex replace value with new value

Tags: java, regex

How to get regex to get the value after **name =** in a file, and replace it.
I have a file called: 'myfile.txt'.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    File TextFile = new File("C:\\text.txt");
    if (TextFile.exists()) {
        try {
            ReplaceWordInFile(TextFile, "haical", "arnanda");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void ReplaceWordInFile(File MyFile, String OldText, String NewText)
        throws IOException {

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("filetemp", ".tmp");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);

    Reader fr = new FileReader(MyFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while (br.ready()) {
        fw.write(br.readLine().replaceAll(OldText, NewText) + "\n");
    }

    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();
    tempFile.renameTo(MyFile);
}
```

**Contents of the file C:\text.txt is:**

```
name = haical
address = Michigan 48309, Amerika Serikat
age = 19
gender = male
activity = school
hoby = hiking, travel
```

If I run the program above in the first line, name = haical will change to name = arnanda.

My problem is that the value from `name` isn't 'haical' but another value, so I want to get the value after **name = blablabla**.

Furthermore, sometimes the statement `name = haical` won't keep it's number of spaces & changes its position.

Example of the contents of the output at a later time is:

```
address = Michigan 48309, Amerika Serikat
name   =    haical  
age = 19
gender = male
activity = school
hoby = hiking, travel
```

So it's not always on the first line and some spaces after the `=` , but it will always be on line starting with **name =**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
....replaceAll("^name\\s*=\\s*" + YourNameVariableToReplace + "\\s*$", "name="+YourNameVariableToInsert)
```

to replace the string. Maybe you need to escape the Name First, if he might contain Regex-Control-Chars.

Comment: Hi dognose, thank you very much, your regex success, i give you vote and true answer. thanks.